# Use python and selenium to input text in search box

Tags: python, selenium

I am building a movie subtitle downloading script. I am planning to download subtitles from [www.isubtitles.net](http://www.isubtitles.net) . i have titles of all movies in my pc in a list called **namelist**. so i plan to send movie names one by one in searchbox of the above site, search them and download subtitles from the first result shown. i use following code

```
homeurl="http://www.isubtitles.net"
for i in range (0, len(namelist)):
    browser.get(homeurl)
    searchele=browser.find_element_by_name("kwd")
    searchele.send_keys(namelist[i])  
    searchele.submit()
```

but python throws error "element not currently interactable and may not be manipulated" in line where we send keys. please look the website html and python code and tell what wrong i did. I am using phantomjs and not firefox for selenium.

Answer (score 2):

You should [wait for the search input to be visible with `WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

for name in namelist:
    browser.get(homeurl)

    searchele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "kwd")))
    searchele.send_keys(name)
    searchele.submit()
```

Also note how I've improved your for loop - you don't have to loop over list indexes.

Comment: now it is giving timeoutException. i also tried increasing the wait time but still error persists.

Comment: @dreadedHarvester interesting, that worked for me, I remember.